# What happens if my Paypal IPNs listener is down?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm handling some purchases through the buy now button. I pass in the notify URL and I implemented an IPN listener to process the IPNs that Paypal sends me after the purchase is gone through.
I was wondering what happens if my IPN listener is down/not able to process the IPN. Does Paypal keep trying sending the IPN until it gets a 200? Do you have suggestions on how to handle such case on my end?

Also, when I check an IPN I only check if the status of the IPN is "VERIFIED" and if the payment_status is "Completed". Only in this case I authorize the purchase on my end. Was wondering what happens if the payment_status is "Pending" instead. Does Paypal keep sending IPNs until the payment is "Completed"? Is there a reference/guide on how to handle all the possible values of payment_status?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It listens for a 200 response, if no 200 response is received it will retry.

`An IPN will be resent for up to four days, with a maximum of 15 retries.`

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, what about the second part of the question? Thanks again

Comment: @otrebla yes for example an echeck well send a payment status as pending, it will send another ipn later once it clears - changing it to completed

Answer (score 0):

PayPal will send an additional IPN when the status of a transaction changes.  So you'd get one IPN when the original pending payment comes through, and then you would get another when that payment clears (or fails) with the same txn_id but the updated payment_status.

Comment: Just wanted to add txn_id will change for refund, reversal, or canceled reversals :)

Comment: In those cases you would also get a parent_txn_id with the original.